# Get all attachment by post excluding featured and content inside

Tags: posts, images, attachments

I have a portfolio where for each item i have some images inside the content, a featured image and a custom filed called "portfolio images".

I want to get all images by post excluding the fetured image and content images.

The code i have is that:

```
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();  
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'portfolio-type');
        /*get the images for the slide on hover by metelidrissi*/
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'post_status' => null,
                'post_parent' => get_the_ID()
            );

            $attachments = get_posts( $args );
            $attachments_portfolio = array();
            if ( $attachments ) {
                $i = 0;
                foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                    var_dump($attachment);
                  $attachments_portfolio[$i] = $attachment->guid;
                  $i++;
                }
            }
```

And I only want to take the images ont his field:

[image]

What i have to do? There is a wat to exclude the images are on the content post and featured one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved. The solution is related with the function **get_post_meta();**

As WordPress as made by the abstraction of differnet kind of posts with the same structure we can define different post types.

Here we can find more information about the function:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

And as you can read, you can find 3 vars $post_id, $key and $single.

**get_post_meta**( int $post_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false )

The second one, with the $key we can indicate wich post we want to retrive, for default it return data for all keys.

In our case we have a template wiht a portfolio with the key *_swimmingpool_image_gallery** and thats the "key" of our problem.

The full code is here:

```
  $image_gallery = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_swimmingpool_image_gallery', true );
                if(!empty($image_gallery)) {
                    $attachments = array_filter( explode( ',', $image_gallery ) );
                    $aImage = array();
                    if ($attachments) {
                        $i = 0;
                        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                            $attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment , 'full');
                            $image = swimmingpool_resize($attachment_url, $slidewidth, $slideheight, true);
                            if(empty($image)) {$image = $attachment_url;}
                            $aImage[$i] = $image;
                            $i++;
                        }
                    }
```

I wish it can help you if you are in the same issue.